# Tableau: Sum of Sessions and Split

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I have the following question!

I have a dataset looking like this.

[image: Dataset]

Apl_id refers to each application, Session for each session the user is in, Date/Time and ser_offered
is the service the user uses.

I need to get the total time that each application lasted which i suppose it's something like
the Max(Date/Time) - Min(Date/Time) for each session and then get the Sum of those.

I want to do that for each the applications that is Completed(from se_offered).

Which is the best way to achieve that?

Thank you in advance and sorry for long post!

Comment: Can you please add your sample data as text rather than image?

Comment: Yes, I agree, you should always give some sample data using code blocks here so that the solution can be worked upon.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following method.
Create two LOD calculated fields as -

`date_of_creation`

```
{FIXED [apl_id] : MAX(
IF [ser_offered] = "Created" then [Date/Time] END
)}
```

and `date_of_completion`

```
{FIXED [apl_id] : MAX(
IF [ser_offered] = "Completed" then [Date/Time] END
)}
```

and then make a third LOD

`desired result`

```
{FIXED [apl_id]: MAX(DATEDIFF('hour', [date_of_creation], [date_of_completion]))}
```

Note: MAX in all three is used for aggregation only, and as such you can take MIN in all three too.
Moreover, first two LOD fields are optional you can directly calculate third one using calculation for those two there.  That should work.  Do tell whether it worked.

Thanks